# Call Buttons Automatically

Tags: java, button, timer, swt

i want to call 3 buttons simultaneously or using delay time.

how to call the buttons automatically with certain time like above?

Comment: question is about awt, gwt, swt..... ???

Comment: i'm using eclipse so it works on swt? right?
how to implement swt?

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT true, doesn't mean projects created in eclipse uses SWT :-)

Comment: `i'm using eclipse so it works on swt?` ---> don't know,  `right?` ---> not sure, `how to implement swt?` ---> don't know something cleaver based on your question and commnet, please where is the problem

Comment: how am i supposed to do with SWT on my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?!

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Menu Item selected " + item);
        if (item == button1) {
            variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object1);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){try{Thread.sleep(5000);onOptionsItemSelected(button3);}catch(Exception ex){}}
    }).start();
        } else if (item == button2) {
            variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object2);
        } else if (item == button3) {
            variabel.setViewMode(ClassOne.Object3);
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){try{Thread.sleep(5000);onOptionsItemSelected(button2);}catch(Exception ex){}}
    }).start();
        }
```

try to move this all in new thread so that ui thread continue to execute.

Comment: i tried this but gives me errors
it says "cannot instatiate the type Runnable"

Comment: @user2857609 Aw! sorry dude, typo mistake, I updated the code, please have a try

Answer (score 0):

just call their listeners OnClick method using Thread.sleep(). and do not forget to separate this in new  thread so that ui thread continue to execute use `Handler` for this.

Comment: Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent myIntent = new
        Intent(view.getContext(), ClassTwo.class);
      startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
     }
     });